# How to invoke a search api from drupal site for Ubuntu Unity lense?

Tags: search

I'm creating a simple Unity lense for my college site which is based on Drupal, but I don't know how to adapt this command for Drupal API. Please help, it's python.

> We now create our query url, using the Wikipedia opensearch API url = ("%s/w/api.php?action=opensearch&limit=25&format=json&search=%s" % (self.wiki, search))

I'm using template to write lense following Wikipedia example http://developer.ubuntu.com/2012/04/how-to-create-a-wikipedia-unity-lens-for-ubuntu/. I don't know python but Im familiar with C. This Drupal API calling is the only problem I have to successfully develop a lense. Please help!

Comment: The example lens build around wikipedia opensearch API. By default there is no opensearch like thing in Drupal's core. What version of Drupal used for your college site? This would require some opensearch module installation in the site.

Comment: I don't know, please look at the site:
http://en.ict.edu.rs/

Comment: Thank you for comment, from your profile I see that you very qualified to help me. Please write down some code with opensearch module.

Answer (score 2):

Your site is running Drupal 6.26
http://en.ict.edu.rs/CHANGELOG.txt

The Unity Lense does not require OpenSearch. You essentially just need to Curl your search results page with a querystring and parse out the search result links.

Eg, send a Curl request with:
http://en.ict.edu.rs/search/node/example

You could show some answers easily that way for any drupal site. You could setup a custom View for searching your content as well if you wanted, or even install the Services module and make a small dedicated search api.

I'm actually running Ubuntu 12.04 here and installed the Lense stuff which looks neat -- but I'm too busy to code up a small example, sorry. Hopefully these thoughts will point you in the right direction.

EDIT: alot of the code is really there already when you start your Lense project. You just need to tear through the results from /search/node/KEYWORDS_HERE you get from the request in Python ...

Comment: Yes true, OpenSearch is not a dependency to build such lense for unity. It is a standard and at least outputs in some structured format like JSON/XML and easy to parse out.